# Why won't my nth-child overlay work with my bootstrap grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap grid on my Jekyll site and I have used the `box-shadow` property to overlay the images with a transparent color with this code:

```
.post-thumbnail {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
```

This works fine, but what I would like to now do is have alternating colors (3 or 4 ideally), so that every 4th overlay color is red, blue, yellow, green, then repeat, for example. I tried using the nth-child property with 1n, 2n, 3n, 4n with the following code but no overlay shows at all when I try that:

```
.post-thumbnail:nth-child(2n) {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
```

Here is my html and css code:

```
.post-thumbnail {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.post-thumbnail:nth-child(2) {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

<div class="blog-wrapper">
  <h1 class="blog-title">Soapbox Blog</h1>
  <div class="container blog-list-container">
    <div class="row">
      {% for post in site.posts %}
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-4 mt-4 thumbnail-parent">
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">
          <div class="post-thumbnail h-100 text-white text-start d-flex align-items-center rgba-black-strong p-5" style="background-image: url('{{site.baseurl}}/assets/images/{{ post.image }}');">
            <!-- Content -->
            <div>
              <h3 class="card-title pt-2"><strong>{{ post.title }}</strong></h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat fus minus error nisi architecto nulla ipsum dignissimos. amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat fus minus error nisi architecto nulla ipsum dignissimos.Odit sed qui, dolorum!.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>  <!-- end of col -->
      {% endfor %}
    </div> <!-- end of row -->
  </div> <!-- end of container -->
</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: `.post-thumbnail` is everytime first child element of his parent, so thats why it is not working. Can you post your code with atleast two elements with that class on it?

Comment: @PetrUnzeitig Thanks for the reply. That is all of the code. There is a for loop that generates each post.

Comment: @PetrUnzeitig So each column is the same - they just have different titles and background images etc, but the same classes for each one.

Comment: This is not how the final html source code looks like, right? Try this selector: `.thumbnail-parent:nth-child(2n) .post-thumbnail {}`